# Count people/object using raspberry PI by OPENCV, TENSORFLOW and PYTHON

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, counter

My code can detect an object now, which is human and other objects. But the issue that i faced now is i want to count the moving human entering a classroom. I would like to count in and out so that i can know the number of people in a room. How can do this? something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEcBnD80nL

How can i make that detected object in rectangle to count in and out when they pass through the red and blue line?

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import sys

# Set up camera constants
IM_WIDTH = 1280
IM_HEIGHT = 720
#IM_WIDTH = 640    Use smaller resolution for
#IM_HEIGHT = 480   slightly faster framerate

# Select camera type (if user enters --usbcam when calling this script,
# a USB webcam will be used)
camera_type = 'picamera'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--usbcam', help='Use a USB webcam instead of picamera',
                action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.usbcam:
camera_type = 'usb'

# This is needed since the working directory is the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append('..')

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'ssdlite_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_05_09'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,'data','mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 90

## Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when the convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, 
max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory. 
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)


# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection 
classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = 
detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Initialize camera and perform object detection.
# The camera has to be set up and used differently depending on if it's a
# Picamera or USB webcam.

# I know this is ugly, but I basically copy+pasted the code for the object
# detection loop twice, and made one work for Picamera and the other work
# for USB.

### Picamera ###
if camera_type == 'picamera':
# Initialize Picamera and grab reference to the raw capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT)
camera.framerate = 10
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT))
rawCapture.truncate(0)

for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):

    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    frame = frame1.array
    frame.setflags(write=1)
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.40)

    # Blue line
    cv2.line(frame, (IM_WIDTH // 2, 0), (IM_WIDTH // 2 , IM_WIDTH), (250, 0, 1), 2)
    # Red line
    cv2.line(frame, (IM_WIDTH // 2 - 50, 0), (IM_WIDTH // 2 - 50, IM_WIDTH), (0, 0, 255), 2)

    # FPS Text
    cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1/time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

    rawCapture.truncate(0)

camera.close()
```

Comment: Please explain a bit further what EXACTLY you want to archive! "something like this" is hardly a sufficient explanation!

Comment: The video is not available for me.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEcBnD80nLg

Comment: Now i can detect a human, but i dont know how to draw the blue line and red line to count in and out and also track the centroid for counting